How to CSS constrain object tag with SVG inside containing div
If you look at this example you will see that if you turn the phone into portrait mode an click one of the right most yellow boxes (to relocate the arrow) you will see scrollbars appear.
I can prevent this by setting overflow to hidden on the whole screen div but why isn't the object tag being contained inside its div?
The "arrow" object has object-fit set to contain and max-width 100%.
This is the CSS
#content {
    height: 92%;
    max-height: 92%;
    flex: 92 92 92%;
    min-height: 0px;
    display: flex;
    order: 2;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--alt-bg-color);
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-size: 2em;
    overflow: none;
}

#content div {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: var(--cell-height);
    background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

#content div div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100%;
    width: var(--cell-height);
    padding: 0.5em;

}
#content div div div {
    display: flex;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.25em;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#modalWait {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#modalWait div {
    flex: 1 1 50%;
    order: 1;
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 50%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    cursor: default;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5em;
    font-size: 2em;
}

#placement {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    visibility: hidden;
}

input[type="button"] {
    margin-right: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 0.66em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #0d0d0d;
    color: #eff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0.8em #eff;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0.15, #ccffff),color-stop(0.51, #00ccdd),color-stop(0.65, #007580));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #ccffff 15%, #00ccdd 51%, #007580 65%);
}

#coords {
    font-size: 1em;
}
    
#continue {
    font-size: 1em;
}

#arrow {
    transform: rotate(var(--arrow-heading));
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-property: transform;
    transform: rotate(var(--arrow-heading));
}

HTML (It's dynamic)


Consider if you can make a [mre] of this issue instead of linking to a webpage and adding a screenshot. That will make it more likely to get an answer.
